# unable to resolve verifyPhoneNumber() in android

Tags: java, android

I am building video calling app in android using java language in which I am getting error in verifyPhoneNumber() in phone authentication in firebase. Below java code,xml files and all dependencies are written.i dont know why i am getting error.I have defined all.I have googled it alot for same

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dekho;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;





import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CountryCodePicker ccp;
    private EditText phoneText;
    private EditText codeText;
    private Button continueAndNextBtn;
    private String checker="",phoneNumber="";
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String mVerificationId;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mSendToken;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ccp=findViewById(R.id.ccp);
        phoneText=findViewById(R.id.phoneText);
        codeText=findViewById(R.id.codeText);
        continueAndNextBtn=findViewById(R.id.continueNextButton);
        relativeLayout=findViewById(R.id.phoneAuth);
        continueAndNextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Javatpoint",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                        60,                 // Timeout duration
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                        this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                        mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks


            }
        });






















    }
}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/register"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp">
    </TextView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/phoneAuth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Phone Number:"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
                    android:id="@+id/ccp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    app:ccp_defaultNameCode="IN" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/phoneText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/codeText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:hint="Write you code here..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phoneAuth"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
        android:drawableTint="@android:color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continueNextButton"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/codeText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

project level dependencies

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dekho"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.9'
    implementation  'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'





}
```

Error log

```
2020-04-16 12:39:03.571 26139-26139/? I/m.example.dekh: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-04-16 12:39:03.638 26139-26139/? W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:82712): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=12437 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c252,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2020-04-16 12:39:03.642 26139-26139/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2020-04-16 12:39:03.717 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/VivoTheme: load old package name start
2020-04-16 12:39:04.220 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/FirebaseApp: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
2020-04-16 12:39:04.220 26139-26139/com.example.dekho I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
2020-04-16 12:39:04.236 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/NightModeController: com.example.dekho = true
2020-04-16 12:39:04.236 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/NightModeController: disable nightmode package:com.example.dekho
2020-04-16 12:39:04.322 26139-26139/com.example.dekho I/FtBuild: getRomVersion mRomVer=9.0
2020-04-16 12:39:04.337 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.338 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.338 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.338 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.338 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.381 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/VivoPhoneWindow: DEBUG_ALIENSCREEN:getRotation mRotation=0
2020-04-16 12:39:04.381 26139-26139/com.example.dekho I/PhoneWindow: initSystemUIColor
2020-04-16 12:39:04.441 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.444 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.497 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.513 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.513 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.513 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.513 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.513 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.514 26139-26139/com.example.dekho W/m.example.dekh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
2020-04-16 12:39:04.534 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/CCP: init:xmlWidth -2
2020-04-16 12:39:04.560 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/CCP: updateLanguageToApply: ENGLISH
2020-04-16 12:39:04.763 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/CCP: updateFormattingTextWatcher: EditText not registered CCP_last_selection
2020-04-16 12:39:04.766 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/CCP: end:xmlWidth -2
2020-04-16 12:39:04.864 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/OpenGLRenderer: Dumper init 4 threads <0x6fcfbd2d40>
2020-04-16 12:39:04.864 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/OpenGLRenderer: <com.example.dekho> is running.
2020-04-16 12:39:04.864 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2020-04-16 12:39:04.865 26139-26139/com.example.dekho I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@a0e3075
2020-04-16 12:39:04.885 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2020-04-16 12:39:04.904 26139-26139/com.example.dekho V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@7c35698, this = DecorView@41e5ef1[MainActivity]
2020-04-16 12:39:04.919 26139-26139/com.example.dekho I/TouchMotionHandler: handler onAttached
2020-04-16 12:39:05.019 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x6fd7cfb000)
2020-04-16 12:39:05.027 26139-26169/com.example.dekho I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-04-16 12:39:05.028 26139-26169/com.example.dekho I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-04-16 12:39:05.028 26139-26169/com.example.dekho I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-04-16 12:39:05.028 26139-26169/com.example.dekho D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-04-16 12:39:05.044 26139-26169/com.example.dekho D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x6fd7cfb000,api=1)
2020-04-16 12:39:05.127 26139-26169/com.example.dekho E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2020-04-16 12:39:06.690 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/TextView: touchFinish handled:false    --- mShowToolbar=false
2020-04-16 12:39:06.712 26139-26139/com.example.dekho I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 4084 bytes, containing 1 windows, 15 views
2020-04-16 12:39:07.075 26139-26139/com.example.dekho D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-04-16 12:39:07.079 26139-26139/com.example.dekho E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dekho, PID: 26139
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.dekho. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:184)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:5)
        at com.example.dekho.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6647)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6620)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:791)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26346)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7081)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
2020-04-16 12:39:07.103 26139-26139/com.example.dekho I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26139 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you provide your error log?

Comment: and where you defined mCallback function

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong set of arguments to `verifyPhoneNumber()`. The `this` keyword inside `OnClickListener` is the problem. Calling `this` inside `setOnClickListener()` refered to the `OnClickListener` your passing and not the activity. So, there you have to use like `MainActivity.this` for it to refer to the activity.

Kindly update the `OnClickListener` as follows

```
continueAndNextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                        60,                 // Timeout duration
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                        MainActivity.this,               // Uses the <ActivityName>.this instead of just "this" Activity (for callback binding)
                        mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks


            }
});
```

**Update**

With regarding OP's crash issue: It says right in the attached stack trace that

**Make sure to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` first.**

So you need to initialize FirebaseApp in the `onCreate()` method of either

1. The activity (Then Firebase will be available to activity context)
2. In the Application class (Firebase will be available to entire app)

by calling

`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);`

Comment: my app is crashing can u help me please to find out the solution of same

Comment: Please attach the crash log

Comment: I have attached crash event log

Comment: please help buddy

Comment: what is problem in that ? buddy

Comment: Please go through the added update section. You forgot to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp in the activity or in the application class. That is what the stacktrace you posted indicates

Comment: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. This error is coming

Comment: buddy I have edited the error log could u please help me to find the solution.The new error is coming Invalid argruments

Comment: sorry but that is not complete error log, it's very hard to infer unless there is complete error log. Also please don't replace an already posted error log with a different one. When your posting a new error log(of a different problem than first one) then add the new one titled "Update" or something. This way when someone else is reading the question and answer they will have a better idea.